# How to compute surface-area using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following 3 inputs: Length, Width, Height.
Using javascript I need to compute the area of a cube, but before that I can't event get the fucntion to work when I press the button "CALCULEAZA". How can I make the "calculeaza" function work?

```
     <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
         <h3>Calculator de Folie</h3>
           <form>
            Lungime:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="lungime"><br>
            Latime:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="latime"><br>
            Inaltime:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="inaltime"><br>
            <button id="submit" onclick="calculeaza()" style="margin-   top:5%;">CALCULEAZA</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="row container fluid">
            <h1 id="value-zone"><span id="value">100</span>m2</h1>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
  <h3>Seminte Demetra CR</h3>        
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('value-zone').hidden = true;
});

function calculeaza(){
    var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lungime').value);
    var y = x/2;
    console.log("aaaaaa");
    document.getElementById('value-zone').hidden = false;
}
</script>
```

I also know that using scripts in the same file is not ok, but I am going to modify it after I undertand how it works. It is my first JS 'thing' I do. Thank you in advance!

Comment: your code does run but since its connected to a SUBMIT button, its submitting the form. The easiest solution is for the button, add type='button'

Comment: Or if you are never going to submit, just remove the form tag all together

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.preventDefault()` to not redirect on click of submit button. Otherwise the code is running fine.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
         <h3>Calculator de Folie</h3>
           <form>
            Lungime:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="lungime"><br>
            Latime:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="latime"><br>
            Inaltime:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="inaltime"><br>
            <button id="submit" onclick="calculeaza()" style="margin-   top:5%;">CALCULEAZA</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="row container fluid">
            <h1 id="value-zone"><span id="value">100</span>m2</h1>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
  <h3>Seminte Demetra CR</h3>        
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('value-zone').hidden = true;
});

function calculeaza(){
    var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lungime').value);
    var y = x/2;
    console.log("aaaaaa");
    document.getElementById('value-zone').hidden = false;
}
$("#submit").click((e)=>{e.preventDefault()})
</script>
```

Comment: You added a script to download jQuery just to add an eventListener. Why?

Comment: The OP is using jquery before hand.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the tag and the single use of `$(document).ready()` in the OP's code. Adding the script tag in your answer threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

change your button to:

`<button id="submit" type="button" onclick="calculeaza()" style="margin-`   top:5%;">CALCULEAZA

by default, the button is of type SUBMIT, which will submit the form. You can use javascript to disable the function or simply make a minor change to your button.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Calculator de Folie</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-form-label" for="length">length</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="length">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-form-label" for="width">width</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="width">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-form-label" for="height">height</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="height">
        </div>
        <button onclick="calculeaza()" style="margin-top:5%;">CALCULEAZA</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row container fluid">
        <h1 id="value-zone"><span id="value">100</span>m2</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('value-zone').hidden = true;

    // calculates the surface area of a cuboid and updates #value with the answer
    function calculeaza() {
        var l = parseFloat(document.getElementById('length').value);
        var w = parseFloat(document.getElementById('width').value);
        var h = parseFloat(document.getElementById('height').value);

        if (!isNaN(l) && !isNaN(w) && !isNaN(h)) {
          document.getElementById('value-zone').hidden = false;
          document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = 2*(l*w + w*h + l*h);
        }

    }
</script>
```

Removed the `<form>` and used bootstrap's "form-groups" instead. No jquery needed for this since it seems you use `document.getElementById` anyways.